# How to get certificate CommonName using x509.load_pem_x509_certificate() Python cryptography?

Tags: python, cryptography, x509, client-certificates

How do I get the `CommonName` from a client certificate using the Python `cryptography` library?

**If using `pyOpenSSL` and `ssl`, I use:**

```
import ssl
from OpenSSL import crypto

cert_raw = 'MIIGXDCCBUSgAwIBAgIJAMgCuv1aXz7l...base64 encoded`
cert_bytes = base64.b64decode(cert_raw)
cert_pem = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(cert_bytes)
cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert_pem)
```

**From there it's straightforward to use:**

```
subject = cert.get_subject()
cn = subject.CN
print(cn)

thethings.com
```

**But I can't seem to find a quick way to do this with the `cryptography` module alone.**

I've tried:

```
import ssl
from cryptography import x509

cert_raw = 'MIIGXDCCBUSgAwIBAgIJAMgCuv1aXz7l...base64 encoded`
cert_bytes = base64.b64decode(cert_raw)
cert_pem = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(cert_bytes)
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_pem.encode('ascii'), default_backend())
```

**But end up with a string to split in order to get CN.**

I'm not confident that `CN` will always be in position `[0]`.

```
subject = cert.subject

cn = subject.rfc4514_string()

cn_value = cn.split(',')[0].split('=')[1]

print(subject)
print(cn)
print(cn_value)

<Name(OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=thethings.com)>
CN=thethings.com,OU=Domain Control Validated
thethings.com
```

**Is there a better way to do this with the `cryptography` module?**

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491107/9014097), but replace `cert_info.issuer` with `cert_info.subject`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Topaco. Do you have a secret recipe for accessing the objects within the `aia` and `sans` extensions? I tried a similar pattern with `aia = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_oid(ExtensionOID.AUTHORITY_INFORMATION_ACCESS)[0].value` but get `TypeError: 'Extension' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can' t answer that right off the bat. My source was the _cryptography_ documentation. Maybe you will find something helpful there.

Comment: All good. Thanks anyway. Your guidance above was very helpful. I was eventually able to get it with `aia_ext = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_oid(ExtensionOID.AUTHORITY_INFORMATION_ACCESS).value` then `issuer_cert = [ia for ia in aia_ext if ia.access_method == AuthorityInformationAccessOID.CA_ISSUERS][0].access_location.value`

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments by @Topaco

```
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
cn = cert.subject.get_attributes_for_oid(NameOID.COMMON_NAME)[0].value
```

Comment: Rather use: (attribute,) = cert.subject.get_attributes_for_oid(NameOID.COMMON_NAME) and then return attribute.value those indexes are not very human readable imo.